# How to count reactions on MessageEmbed Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot for a project for college, its purpose is to schedule events. FYI, this export default as ICommand is in TS. It is the basic module.exports equivalent in JS.

I am also using a library, the 'wokcommands' from WorkOffKeys. It was a tutorial I was following on YouTube.

Here is my index.ts file:

```
import Discord, { Intents } from 'discord.js'
import wok from 'wokcommands'
import path from 'path'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Manager is online!')
    
    new wok(client, {
        commandDir: path.join(__dirname, 'commands'),
        typeScript: true,
        testServers: 'number'
    })
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

And here is my file with a specified command (since I am keeping all commands seperate):

```
import { MessageEmbed } from "discord.js";
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";

export default {
    category: 'testing',
    description: 'send an embed',
    slash: true,
    testOnly: true, 
    permissions: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
    options: [
        {
            name: 'title',
            description: 'Please provide a title for the event you wish to schedule:',
            required: true,
            type: 3

        },
        {
            name: 'description',
            description: 'Please provide a description for your event:',
            required: true,
            type: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'color',
            description: 'Please select the color of your event message from 1 - 256:',
            required: true,
            type: 3
        }
    ],
    callback: ({user, message, args}) => {
        const checkmark = '\:white_check_mark:'
        const not_going = '\:no_entry:'
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor({
            name: user.username
        })
        .setTitle(args[0])
        .setDescription(args[1])
        .setColor(parseInt(args[2]))
        .addFields([
            {
                name: `${checkmark} Going`,
                value: `${message.reactions.cache.get(checkmark)?.count}`,
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: `${not_going} Not Going`,
                value: '2',
                inline: true
            }
        ])
        return embed
    } 
} as ICommand
```

My question is, how can I have the bot count the amount of reactions that the message has received? I am currently getting an error as such:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reactions')`

Also, is there any way to have the bot send the message with reactions automatically set up? So that instead of me, the owner, having to manually setup reactions, the bot will do it instead with a value of -1 on the count then (I would like the bot to not count its own reaction when sending the initial message)?

My experience with asynchronous programming is minimal, so please excuse me if the answer is obvious and I'm just inexperienced.

Thank you to all in advace.

Comment: Your property message is undefined, can you show us the messageCreate event where you define message & run the commands?

Comment: This is all the code I have. I guess the wokcommands import, when it returns an embed, returns that messageCreate event as an embedded message.

Comment: I was trying some stuff and this produced no error in the console, but wrote out "undefined" in the field on Discord itself (this is the value filed for checkmark, Going): value: `${client.emojis.cache.get(checkmark)}`